# What can I mix with a sweet liquor to cut its sweetness?

Tags: liqueur

I have a flavored liquor, Salted Caramel Crown Royal, that is really sweet. What kind of mixer could I use to cut its sweetness?

Comment: Might be a better fit on alcohol.stackexchange.com

Comment: Lemon or lime juice, would help, also a splash of bitters, but yeah this is better asked on alcohol.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated, otherwise it risks being closed as an opinion based recipe request

Comment: Always better to close as a duplicate than as off-topic...  **;-)** @Erica

Comment: Don't disagree! Didn't know about the duplicate though :)

Answer (score 4):

Add a splash to hot coffee for a fabulous liquor coffee, or use with cold brewed coffee in a Tiramisu dessert. Adding fat (i.e. mascarpone) and bitterness (i.e. coffee) or sourness (i.e. citrus suggested in first answer, or natural yoghurt) will help balance the sweetness.  Also chilling sweet food and drink reduces their detectable sweetness - perhaps make an alcoholic sorbet or frappe.